# Losing ability to update after recreating context

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, objectcontext

I have this design problem. I have a bulk update/insert feature built into my EF generic repository.

Two things can happen within that feature: I'm just adding the entity to the context and incrementing a counter or actually committing changes to the database ie: SaveChanges() (counter == commit treshold)

When I am calling SaveChanges, I also like to Dispose of the context and recreate it as a way to clear up ressources.

The thing is that I lose the ability to update entities after disposing. Here's my Update method:

```
public void Update(T entity, int batchSize)
{

    try
    {
        System.Data.EntityState entityState = (System.Data.EntityState)BLHelper.GetValue(entity, "EntityState");

         if (entityState == System.Data.EntityState.Detached)
             this.Attach(entity);

         //The next line will work so as long as QueueContextChanges() did not
         //save changes and then  Dispose of the context... 
         //After that, I'll get an exception that:
         //'ObjectStateManager does not contain an ObjectStateEntry with a reference to an object...'

         _context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(entity, System.Data.EntityState.Modified);



         QueueContextChanges(batchSize); //Just increments a counter or calls SaveChanges()
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
}


public void Attach(T entity)
{
    _objectSet.Attach(entity);
}

public void QueueContextChanges(int batchSize)
{
    if (_commitCount == _commitThreshold || _counter == batchSize || batchSize == 1)
    {
        try
        {
            SaveChanges();
        }
        catch
        {
                //throw;
        }

        _commitCount = 0;

    }
    else
        _commitCount++;

    _counter++;
}

public void SaveChanges()
{
    try
    {
        _context.SaveChanges();
        _context.Dispose();
        _context = null;
        _context = SelectContext<T>(); //This methods knows which context to return depending of type of T...
     }
     catch
     {
        //TODO
     }
}
```

Can you think of a better (and working) design ? The ability to clear memory usage while adding/updating 500,000 rows is kind of important for the moment.

Can detaching entities after SaveChange() help save on ressources so that I won't have to dispose of the context ?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the content of the `this.Attach(entity)` method please?

Comment: From design point of view I think using EF to do bulk inserts/updates is not a good idea.

Comment: Can SqlBulkCopy let me know which entities did not insert/update properly then ?